# Ray | tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

I am trying to use Ray to find hidden layer size with keras but I got this error

> Tune detects GPUs, but no trials are using GPUs. To enable trials to
> use GPUs, set tune.run(resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}...) which allows
> Tune to expose 1 GPU to each trial. You can also override
> `Trainable.default_resource_request` if using the Trainable API.
> 2022-08-30 04:14:49,732   WARNING trial_runner.py:1575 -- You are trying
> to access _search_alg interface of TrialRunner in TrialScheduler,
> which is being restricted. If you believe it is reasonable for your
> scheduler to access this TrialRunner API, please reach out to Ray team
> on GitHub. A more strict API access pattern would be enforced starting
> 1.12s.0   (BroadModel pid=17115) 2022-08-30 04:14:54.026559: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to
> cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

I use this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import ray
    from ray.tune.schedulers import PopulationBasedTraining

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--smoke-test", action="store_true", help="Finish quickly for testing"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--server-address",
        type=str,
        default=None,
        required=False,
        help="The address of server to connect to if using Ray Client.",
    )
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    if args.smoke_test:
        ray.init(num_gpus=1)
        print(num_gpus)
    elif args.server_address:
        ray.init(f"ray://{args.server_address}")

    pbt = PopulationBasedTraining(
        perturbation_interval=2,
        hyperparam_mutations={
            "dropout": lambda: np.random.uniform(0, 1),
            "lr": lambda: 10 ** np.random.randint(-10, 0),
        },
    )

    tuner = tune.Tuner(
    BroadModel,
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="pbt_babi_memnn",
            stop={"training_iteration": 4 if args.smoke_test else 100},
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            scheduler=pbt,
            metric="mean_accuracy",
            mode="max",
            num_samples=2,
        ),
        param_space={
            "finish_fast": args.smoke_test,
            "batch_size": 32,
            "epochs": 1,
            "dropout": 0.3,
            "lr": 0.01,
        },
    )

    tuner.fit()
```

What is my mistake?
How can I force ray to use GPU?

Comment: Which GPU do you have?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy GTX1070